# JsessionId spoofing - Jboss 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jsessionid

My application is running in jboss 7 and the sessions are being maintained by using the jsessionid cookie, which is marked secure and httponly. But even with this, if I am able to get any user's jsessionid cookie value, I will be able to spoof as the user. Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a session for a user on your server, you need to match a request from a user to its session, it's the goal of the JSESSIONID cookie.

This is why you need to secure it by adding "secure" (this cookie will only be sent over https to prevent network sniffing) and "HttpOnly" (to disable access to this cookie by client javascript code) options.

You can add other mitigation methods by checking change in user's IP address (but will break 3G/WIFI change for legit users), user agent string, ... 
But in practice, if you have access to the JSESSIONID cookie you can have access to these data too.

You can take a look at OWASP Session Management Cheat Sheet for more :
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet